# is Dictionary.Keys order guarantee to be the same if the Dictionary has not been modified?

Tags: c#, dictionary

based on the doc

> The order of the keys in the Dictionary.KeyCollection is
>   unspecified

Ok I'm fine with that. But what if I did not modify the dictionary's key nor its values.

Lets say if I do

```
Dictionary.Keys.ToList();
Thread.Sleep(5000)
Dictionary.Keys.ToList();
```

can I safely assume the order would be the same?

Comment: It's normally fastest to look at the source directly: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,9a3c0cb5c149c9f7,references

Comment: `can I safely assume the order would be the same?` If you are talking about the **contract** (since the contract says it is unspecified, **not** guaranteed) - **No**. If you are talking about a specific **implementation** you can look at the source code and reason about its behaviour. This is problematic in two ways (generally speaking) - a) You may misunderstand the code, thus your reasoning about it may be flawed b) There is no guarantee that other implementations (e.g. future implementations) will act the same way since they only need to meet the **contract** not the current implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterating a `Dictionary` is a deterministic process. It is based on the implementation-specific way the items are organized inside hash "buckets", tie resolution, and insertion order.

However, the order of iterating a dictionary does not depend on anything arbitrary that could change between iterations. You can see how the iteration is done in the source of `Dictionary.Enumerator` [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/System/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,d655c13004d3ab43): its `bool MoveNext()` method walks `dictionary.entries[index]` array one by one, stopping when the first unused element is reached. Hence you can safely assume that the order of iterating a dictionary is not going to change when you do not modify the dictionary between iterations.